# App Engine Restarts

Tags: google-app-engine

I know that the App Engine restarts to apply fixes etc. If there is more than one instance of your App Engine, does it restart those at the same time, so will that allow a more "100%" uptime if there is more than one instance running.

We had been deploying daily as that seemed to allow Google to apply fixes, but in the past few weeks, we have seen many more starts etc.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in another [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/929823/should-i-expect-google-app-engine-to-randomly-restart-instances), according to the documentation there are 2 main reasons for an unexpected restart:

> - Instances restarted on a weekly basis [[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/how-instances-are-managed)].
> - A health check giving an HTTP code different from 200 [[2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/how-instances-are-managed#health_checking)].